# Rust Lifetime of returned value should be equal to the struct lifetime

Tags: methods, rust, lifetime

Let's suppose I have code like this:

```
struct Struct0 {
   s1: Struct1,
   v: Vec<Box<dyn Tr>>
}

impl Struct0 {
    fn a(&mut self) {
        self.v = self.s1.func();
    }
}

struct Struct1 {}

impl<'a> Struct1 {
    fn func(&'a self) -> Vec<Box<dyn Tr + 'a>> {
        vec![Box::new(Struct2 { some_reference: &self } )]
    }
}

trait Tr {
    //...
}

struct Struct2<'a> {
   some_reference: &'a Struct1
}

impl Tr for Struct2<'_> {
    //...
}

fn main() {
    
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/main.rs:8:26
  |
8 |         self.v = self.s1.func();
  |                          ^^^^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 7:5...
 --> src/main.rs:7:5
  |
7 | /     fn a(&mut self) {
8 | |         self.v = self.s1.func();
9 | |     }
  | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:8:18
  |
8 |         self.v = self.s1.func();
  |                  ^^^^^^^
  = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
 --> src/main.rs:8:18
  |
8 |         self.v = self.s1.func();
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  = note: expected `std::vec::Vec<std::boxed::Box<(dyn Tr + 'static)>>`
             found `std::vec::Vec<std::boxed::Box<dyn Tr>>`
```

I would like to tell the Rust compiler that that the lifetime of the returned value should be the lifetime of the Struct1. That vector (with its values) should live as long as the struct from which that method is called. How can I say that?

Comment: There's no way to express that in safe Rust, as Rust does not support self-referential lifetimes.

Comment: How can I get that assignment to work then?

Comment: Can you post the full code? I didn't see the `assignment` in your code. Also, you could use unsafe to skip rust lifetime check, but it's highly not recommended to do so unless necessary. Sometimes, you need to think of other ways to express your code